# Как указать путь к изображению Picasso.get().load(Путь к изображению )

Tags: picasso

В MainActivity в цикле изменяется имена картинок для добавления в ArrayList. Тип String. Картинок много, они все в папке drawable, решил добавлять их в цикле изменяя имя.
Далее в Picasso в адаптере пытаюсь их вставить. Но ничего не выходит. Тип String в Picasso.get().load(String path).into.....
Вопрос в том что если писать в Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.img1).into(holder.imageView); всё работает. Но если написать вместо R.drawable.img1 переменную типа String в которой записано R.drawable.img1 ничего не работает. Как должен быть написан путь или какой тип переменной надо вставлять?

```
  private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArrayList<ImagesItem> images = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycleViewImages);

    for(int i = 1; i < 16 ; i++){
        String path =  "R.drawable.img" + i;
        images.add(new ImagesItem(path, i));
}

    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(images);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,5));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

}

Adapter

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.NoteViewHolder>{

private ArrayList<ImagesItem> images;

public Adapter(ArrayList<ImagesItem> images) {
    this.images = images;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);
    return new NoteViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ImagesItem note = images.get(position);
    Picasso.get().load(note.getImageView()).into(holder.imageView);
    holder.textView.setText(Integer.toString(note.getNumber()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return images.size();
}

class NoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView textView;

    public NoteViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: String imageUrl = getURLForResource(R.drawable.image); или так String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.image;

Comment: public String getURLForResource (int resourceId) {
    //use BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID instead of R.class.getPackage().getName() if both are not same
    return Uri.parse("android.resource://"+R.class.getPackage().getName()+"/" +resourceId).toString();
}

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getURLForResource (int resourceId) {
    //use BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID instead of R.class.getPackage().getName() if both are not same
    return Uri.parse("android.resource://"+R.class.getPackage().getName()+"/" +resourceId).toString();
}

String imageUrl = getURLForResource(R.drawable.image); или так String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.image;
```